# How to make a function to return next string in given order in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to make a function that list strings ordered first by length and then by alphabetical order. I tried to do it like

```
 public static string nextstring(string s) {
     String next = ((char)(s[0] + 1)).ToString();
     return next;
 }
```

But how can I modify the code such that it works for longer string? My goal is to print all strings in order like a, b, c, ..., z, aa, ab, ac,...,az,ba,...,zz, aaa...

Comment: What arguments are you supplying to this function and what is the expected out come? It isn't clear what you are asking

Comment: Please clarify why you expect zz to come before aaa. Are you wanting to sort both alphabetically and by length?

Comment: The list you give is not in alphabetical order. In an alphabetical list, "aaa" comes before "zz". if you want alphabetical order, you want a, aa, aaa, aaaa, aaaaa, aaaaaa, .... up to infinity, before starting on b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, think of the algorithm to increment a decimal number:

- First thing you do is incrementing the least significant digit
- If the value of the digit after an increment is below ten, you are done
- If the value is ten, set the digit to zero, and increment the next higher digit
- If there is no next higher digit to increment, insert `1` in front of the number

Your strings could be thought of as numbers in base-26 system, with a slight twist (no zeros). You start with the increment of the last letter; if the result is past `'z'`, go back to `'a'`, and move to the next letter up; if you exhausted all letters, insert `'a'` in front of the value.

Here is one possible implementation of this approach:

```
static string Increment(string s) {
    var chars = s.ToCharArray();
    int carry = 1;
    var i = s.Length-1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        chars[i] += (char)carry;
        if (chars[i] <= 'z') {
            carry = 0;
            break;
        }
        chars[i] = 'a';
        carry = 1;
        i--;
    }
    var res = new string(chars);
    return (i == -1 && carry != 0) ? "a"+res : res;
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/Ezxx0U)

Comment: Agree...you'll need the special case when the you reach z...but absolutely right

Comment: Some c code that helps with the common problem of dealing with this in Excel https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-excel-column-name-given-number/

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstood your request and what you are looking for is an ordered incrementing sequence of characters, this implementation should produce exactly what you are looking for:

```
private static List<String> CharCombos(Int32 maximumSize)
{
    const String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    IEnumerable<String> projection = alphabet.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
    List<String> result = new List<String>(projection);

    for (Int32 j = 1; j < maximumSize; ++j)
    {
        projection = projection.SelectMany(x => alphabet, (x, y) => x + y);
        result.AddRange(projection);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The following code:

```
foreach (String combo in CharCombos(3))
    Console.WriteLine(combo);
```

will produce:

```
a
b
...
y
z
aa
ab
...
zy
zz
aaa
aab
...
zzy
zzz
```

You can see a working example [here](http://rextester.com/TMB71066). I know this changes your currently implemented logic, proposing a new approach instead of properly modifying the existing one, but I hope you can appreciate it anyway.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it realizes the entire -- possibly huge -- list up front. Challenge: instead return `IEnumerable<String>` and yield the results one at a time. Do you see how?

Comment: Ah sure, you mean using yield return? But I don't know if this can address the OP's problem anyway unless iterating until the target string is found and then picking the next one. This risks to be very inefficient, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
string SingleEntry(int number)
    {
        char[] array = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToArray();
        Stack<string> entry = new Stack<string>();
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        int bas = 26;

        int remainder = number, index = 0;
        do
        {
            if ((remainder % bas) == 0)
            {
                index = bas;
                remainder--;
            }
            else
                index = remainder % bas;

            entry.Push(array[index].ToString());
            remainder = remainder / bas;
        }
        while (remainder != 0);

        string s = "";
        while (entry.Count > 0)
        {
            s += entry.Pop();
        }
        return s;
    }
```